# PHP регулярные выражения форматирование

Tags: php

Есть строка

```
 Текст >>123 текст и ещё текст
```

Как отсюда выделить >>123 (после стрелочек только цифры) и заменить например на `<a href=\"#">`*тут то что выделили*`</a>`

Вот так пытался сделать:

```
preg_replace("/&gt;&gt;([0-9])<br \/>/Usi","<a href=\"#\\1\">>>\\1</a><br \/>",$str)
```

Comment: Какие попытки решения поставленной задачи были предприняты Вами?

Comment: Сейчас использую такой вариант. Но он работает только если после строки идет перенос
preg_replace("/&gt;&gt;([0-9])<br \/>/Usi","<a href=\"#\\1\">>>\\1</a><br \/>",$str)

Comment: код, предоставленный в комментарии абсолютно нечитабельный. Вставьте его в пост

Comment: все готово 1234567

Comment: Зачем в регулярном выражении `<br \/>`? Именно из-за этого 'он работает только если после строки идет перенос'

Comment: странно, уже забыл зачем я это делал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм, [так](http://ideone.com/kJuqcK)?

```
<?php
$str = 'Текст >>123 текст и ещё текст';

// Тут неясность - вставить после # найденное или нет. В запросе - нет, в попытке решения - есть. Тут вставляется, если не надо, убери первый \\1
$newStr = preg_replace('/>>(\d+)/i', '<a href="#\\1">>>\\1</a>', $str);

print $newStr;
```

Comment: Да, все отлично. Я уже понял где была ошибка. В запросе я так указал что бы было проще объяснить.